# Server-side setInterval/clearInterval with Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor, setinterval

I'm creating a Meteor app that has some simple timers in it. Pressing the start or stop buttons on a timer each call a method to set or clear an interval timer, among other things. When I `setInterval`, I store the resulting object in the current timer document so that it is easy to find later when I want to clear the interval timer. This is where I'm running into issues.

When running `Meteor.setInterval()` server-side, it returns an object. According to the node.js docs, this is normal. If I log the resulting object after creation, it returns this:

```
{ _idleTimeout: 5000,
  _idlePrev: 
   { _idleNext: [Circular],
     _idlePrev: 
      { _idleTimeout: 5000,
        _idlePrev: [Object],
        _idleNext: [Circular],
        _idleStart: 1393271941639,
        _onTimeout: [Function],
        _repeat: false },
     msecs: 5000,
     ontimeout: [Function: listOnTimeout] },
  _idleNext: 
   { _idleTimeout: 5000,
     _idlePrev: [Circular],
     _idleNext: 
      { _idleTimeout: 5000,
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idleStart: 1393271941639,
        _onTimeout: [Function],
        _repeat: false },
     _idleStart: 1393271941639,
     _onTimeout: [Function],
     _repeat: false },
  _idleStart: 1393271943127,
  _onTimeout: [Function: wrapper],
  _repeat: true }
```

If I log the object after retrieving it from my document, I get this:

```
{ _idleTimeout: 5000,
  _idlePrev: null,
  _idleNext: null,
  _idleStart: 1393271968144,
  _repeat: true }
```

So, using `clearInterval` with this does not work. Here is my server-side code:

```
Meteor.methods({

    play: function(entry){ //entry is the document
         var currentPlayTimer = entry; //Global variable for the interval timer
         Entries.update({_id: currentPlayTimer._id},{$set:{playing:true}}); //This is mostly to set the status of the play button for the client
         var IntervalId = Meteor.setInterval(function(){Entries.update({_id: currentPlayTimer._id},{$inc:{time:1},$set:{intervalId: IntervalId}});},5000); //Increment by 1 every 5 seconds, put the object from the interval timer into the current document
         console.log(IntervalId);
    },

    stop: function(entry){ //entry is the document
         var currentPlayTimer = entry;
         IntervalId = currentPlayTimer.intervalId;
         console.log(IntervalId);
         Meteor.clearInterval(IntervalId);
         Entries.update({_id: currentPlayTimer._id},{$set:{playing:false, intervalId: null}});

    }
});
```

Also, you will notice that in the play method, I set `intervalId` inside of the `setInterval` function. I tried this in desperation, and it worked. For some reason, if I try to update the document right after creating the interval timer with `Entries.update({_id: currentPlayTimer._id},{$set:{intervalId: IntervalId}})`, it fails.

All of this worked great as client-side code, but I need this to be done server side. I want the timer to keep going at the correct pace whether you have the page open on 5 devices or none.

Thanks for your help! This project is my first using Meteor or anything on Node, and I am really enjoying it so far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is essentially down to two issues: firstly, that the implementations of `setInterval` and `clearInterval` are different on the client (at least in Chrome) and in Node, and secondly that [you can't serialise functions in BSON](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification), which means that all your methods, and properties containing methods, are being dropped from the object when you try to insert it as a document on the server.  That's why the object you subsequently retrieve is so much simpler/smaller, and why you can't pass it to `clearInterval`, as it's missing most of the required information.

If you log the return value of `setInterval` in the client, you'll notice that it's just an integer, which can of course be serialised, and so you get exactly the same thing out of the MongoDB as you put in, and `clearInterval` works fine.  I am no expert at all on the client implementation of `set...` and `clearInterval`, but frankly a four-digit integer doesn't seem particularly robust for this purpose, although it does have some advantages that you've identified.

In summary, I don't think you're going to be able to go about things the way in which you're attempting on the server, unless somebody else can think of a smart way of serialising the part of the `interval` object which is required for clearing it and rebuilding an appropriate object once it's been retrieved, but this requires more knowledge of Node than I possess.  Otherwise, I think you have two options:

- Simply store your intervals in memory in some kind of vanilla javascript object.
- Use an alternative object for timing which would allow you to store a serialisable identifier.  I have used the [`meteor-cron`](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-cron) package in the past, albeit briefly, and it may be worth a look to see if this is possible using that package or some derivative thereof.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. Here is what I did, for anyone else with this issue:

Create an array to hold `setInterval` objects
`var intervalArray = [];`

Push the object (`IntervalId`) into the array, storing the position. This is just a number, so store I can store it in a MongoDB document.
`intervalArrayPosition = intervalArray.push(IntervalId) - 1;`

Later, read the position back out and clear like this:
`Meteor.clearInterval(intervalArray[intervalArrayPosition]);`

Comment: I'm wanting to do something similar, `setInterval` on the server even if a user closes out their browser, it should keep running, until they log in and stop it - hence same problem as you wanting to save to the database. How does `var intervalArray = []` persist after log out?

Comment: Thank you , this was very helpfull